# Laravel 5.6 sent gmail mail to myself

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail, laravel-5.6

I want to sent an email to myself so to say.
I basically have a form and if the user clicks on submit I want to receive and email which the proper Information.

So far I linked my gmail account in my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypw
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I did also allow secure apps and generates a Password for this.

Furthermore I created a Mailable class which Looks like this:

```
class InquirySent extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->data['email'])
                    ->view('emails.contacts.inquiry');
    }
}
```

And in my ContactController I do following:

```
public function sent(ContactRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    Mail::to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))->send(new InquirySent($data));
}
```

But I get this error:

> exception : "Swift_TransportException" file :
>   "D:\laragon\www\tom\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php"
>   line : 269 message : "Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.googlemail.com [ #0]"

Comment: That exception's pretty clear. You can't connect to `smtp.googlemail.com` on that server on that port.

Comment: @tadman so which port is needed

Comment: try using mailtrap for testing and sparkpost for live. much easier to setup than google.

Comment: What I mean is this could be some kind of firewall issue, or perhaps a misconfiguration. What you have here should work [as per examples](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-mail-google-apps-for-work?page=1) barring network-related issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think the config file is cache so you need to run the following command in terminal.

php artisan config:cache

This will clear and recache the config file.

Comment: ok I get this error now `file
:
"D:\laragon\www\tom\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php"
line
:
536
message
:
"Trying to get property of non-object"`